# No leaks appearing in Instruments, even though I'm sure they exist

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm checking for leaks in Instruments, and I've set to check every second, but no leaks are appearing.

I'm sure there must be some in my app, is there anything which could stop these from appearing? Is there a good way I can create a leak so that I can test if leaks do show up in Instruments?

Thanks!

Comment: "...I'm sure there must be some in my app..." - what evidence do you have to support this assertion?  Do you not believe your measurement devices, or do you lack confidence in your measuring skills?

Comment: Hey! Just in case you're new to the Instruments leaks tool, here's a tip to get the most out of it: In the bottom bar, click the icon that shows three items slightly indented. It presents a nice list of leaks. Then click the last icon in that set (a rectangle half-filled) to show the "Extended Detail". You can select an individual leak, and it'll give you a full stack trace and you can jump into the code. Pretty slick! Sorry if you already knew, but I was so impressed when I finally found that...

Comment: "...or do you lack confidence in your measuring skills?" The first time I used the leaks tool, I doubted both my understanding of programming in Objective-C and in my measuring skills. :-)

Comment: If you want a good answer to this, its probably a good idea to describe why you are sure and give sample code of a leak that doesn't show up.

Comment: FWIW, I've intentionally added leaks, and Instruments didn't find them.  So don't take the tool's results as gospel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only going to find leaks with a tool if an object is allocated but no longer referenced.  Another type of "leak" is to hold a reference to something that you didn't intend to.  This typically happens with a collection like a hash table or a dictionary where key/value pairs get left in the collection that the programmer has forgotten about.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a leak is easy:

```
id someObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
someObject = nil;
```

Drop some code like that into your app, and you should definitely see a leak show up in Instruments.

Comment: The problem is that if you don't do the "someObject = nil;" part, which you are unlikely to do when you are not intentionally trying to create leaks, then Instruments often doesn't find them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure as clemahieu postulated, what you are really seeing are over-retained objects - you think you have freed them but they still are being retained.

One quick sanity check for this is to set breakpoints in dealloc and see if the classes you expect to be freed really are.

You can also use the memory tracking Instrument (not leaks) to see what memory is still around - just make sure to select the "created and still living" option to check out just what what objects are still around.