# Leaks never show up in Xcode 6.1.1 Instruments tool

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

[Similar to this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056073/no-leaks-appearing-in-instruments-even-though-im-sure-they-exist), I'm trying to find leaks in an app that keeps giving memory warnings, but even though I've purposely put in a few leaks as a sanity check like this for ex:

```
id someObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
someObject = nil;
```

nothing ever shows up in the Leaks section of the Instruments tool when using the Leaks profile with XCode 6.1.1. I feel like I'm missing something basic to "enable" leak detection. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using ARC? In so, then that's not a leak.

If you are not using ARC, then please note that the static analyzer ("Analyze" on Xcode's "Product" menu) is absolutely brilliant at identifying all sorts of problems. It would have immediately identified the issue you reference in your question, bringing it to your attention far more quickly. Make sure you have a clean bill of health from the static analyzer.

But, to your broader question,  lots of memory problems (greedy caches, abandoned memory, strong reference cycles, etc.) are not identified by leaks tool. Use Allocations tool, drag thru portion of graph to select range, and look at the objects allocated but not released. Leaks tool won't identify many of these issues, but Allocations tool will.

See WWDC 2014 video [Fixing Memory Problems](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=410) or WWDC 2013 [iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242).

Comment: Thanks for tips and links. I should have been clear, the app is non-ARC.

Comment: Very good. By the way, check out the static analyzer, which would have brought this issue to your attention far more effectively than Instruments ever could hope to.

Comment: Marking as answer because those WWDC videos were quite helpful. One thing I still don't understand though is why I cant get the Leaks profile to work on a real device. It only seems to give leak data in the simulator.